# How to stop JDialog from requesting focus every time?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I wrote a data plotter application a while ago, which has an autoreload feature. Both load and reload action cause a JDialog with a cancel button to pop up. In autoreload mode this happens every several seconds, with the JDialog window requesting focus every time.

I tried calling `setFocusableWindowState(false)` on the `JDialog` instance, but that did not make any difference. Could it be because it's a `JDialog` rather than some other subclass of `Window`?

UPDATE: `setFocusableWindowState(false)` does work, I was just stupidly running the wrong jar file. Long story. Anyway, I'm not deleting the question because when I did a little bit of research before posting it, I saw a few other people having trouble with similar issues. This is the solution :)

Comment: `JDialog` is a subclass of `Window`. You could try setting up so the window doesn't show up when in auto mode or try using a `JWindow`, but you'll lose the window border

Comment: `setFocusableWindowState(false)` where are you putting this line ?

Comment: @Sharpedge after I create an instance (it's actually a subclass of `JDialog`), which in sets an icon and adds a window listener in the constructor.  This happens before the `setVisible()` call.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I guess I was confused, I thought that the title was supposed to be a malformed English question. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs Sarcasm isn't needed. Your title should be something like "JDialog requesting focus when it shouldn't", or something of the like. Perhaps "headline" would have been a better word than "summary", but my point remains, albeit changed.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I disagree about the sarcasm. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs Then you won't do well here. See, there's this thing called "people who want to help", and when you're a dick to them, they stop trying to help you. Simple! Now, all you need to do is avoid being sarcastic and, if you don't want to follow their advice, don't be a dick about it. Maybe you could start being nice by accepting one of the answers.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes We're really getting off topic here, but I would count you among people who leave useless comments written in a didactic tone. I answered my own question, as you can probably see, but I can't accept it for two days. Just bear with me.

Comment: Well, I apologize for not seeing that one of the answers was left by you. The other one might be a better choice anyway, since it provides more information to new users and you'd get rep from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put these two statements, in the constructor of your class extending `JDialog`

```
setFocusableWindowState(false);
setFocusable(false);
```

So when each time the JDialog appears, the parent container will still have focus on whatever it had.

Answer (score 0):

`setFocusableWindowstate()` does work, after all. It was my own stupid mistake: I was running the wrong jar file, i.e. not the one with the fix. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.